# Inverse Limit of Finite Direct Product of Groups/TopSpaces

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, category-theory, limits-colimits

I’m wondering if the inverse limit of a finite direct product of groups $G_{i,j}$ or topological spaces $X_{i,j}$ is isomorphic to the direct product of the inverse limits of $G_{i,j}$ or $X_{i,j}$, respectively.

I’m thinking that both of these are true but I’m not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to me you need two indices $G_{ij}$. Unless you are taking the inverse limit of a constant sequence?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I just fixed it.

Comment: In more categorical terms, it sounds like you're asking if the [(categorical) limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(category_theory)) of a finite (categorical) product is the finite product of the limits of the components. The answer is "yes" because finite (or even infinite) categorical products are categorical limits themselves, and categorical limits commute. Thus generally, the limit of a product is the product of the limits of the components (assuming everything exists, which is the case for the examples you gave since they're complete).

Comment: Great, thank you!