Confusion on isomorphism profinite completion integers
Question: Prove that $\hat{\mathbb{Z}} \cong \prod_{p} \mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is an isomorphism of topological rings.
Own attempts: Although this specific question has been asked quite a few times here, there is a part of the proof where I am confused.
I came to the part where I have to prove that the map
$f : \prod_{p} \mathbb{Z}_{p} \rightarrow \varprojlim_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \prod_{p} \mathbb{Z} / p^{e_{p}(n)} \mathbb{Z}$
is an isomorphism of topological rings. However, I am struggling to show that this map is surjective and continuous. I know that $f$ is continuous if and only if every map $f_{m} = p_{m} \circ f$ is continuous, where $p_{m}$ denotes the projection
$p_{m} : \varprojlim_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \prod_{p} \mathbb{Z} / p^{e_{p}(n)} \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \prod_{p} \mathbb{Z} / p^{e_{p}(m)} \mathbb{Z}$,
but I think I am not quite understanding how continuity works here. Perhaps I am not understanding continuity at all in this settings (what are open sets in the topologies of these rings?). I hope someone can clear things up for me.

Are you working with the definition of the $p$-adic integers as the inverse limit of $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$?

Yes @UriGeorgePeterzil

I would advise you to look at the discussion in this question for formal reasoning: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3265815/inverse-limit-of-finite-direct-product-of-groups-topspaces

If you want a more hands-on approach, you can realize inverse limits of rings as closed subrings of the product ring of the limiting rings (with an explicit description as sequences of elements in the rings $R_{n+1}$ which project to the corresponding element in $R_n$). Then the problem in the composition you have defined restricts to the continuity of the projection to each of the elements of the limit.

I  topological rings

@HighAsAKiteOnMath the name checks out

@ByteBlitzer I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  Plz explain
